# Select multiple date ranges for the same event using Full Calendar

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, date-range, fullcalendar-5

I'm currently using full calendar library V5 for my Angular project and I was wondering if there is possibility to set multiple date ranges for the same event for example,

If I have an event which is interviewing with candidates (event), and I want to set on calendar that I've 3 slots associated to this event, today , tomorrow, after tomorrow, how do I send these data to BE?

I've tried to follow documentation but didn't catch anything that could help.

I expect to get any entry key for this

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a recurring event? You can read about it here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events